# Android NullPointerException - when do fields get garbage collected?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, garbage-collection, activity-lifecycle

I have something like this in an Android activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPreferencesViewModel = new MainActivityPreferencesViewModel();

    mButton.setOnClickListener({ 
          mPreferencesViewModel.getSomething()
   })
}
```

Along with a rarely reported `NullPointerException` **crash** at the `getSomething()` line. So basically, the `mPreferencesViewModel` is null.

To clarify: there is no piece of code in the activity that reset the field into null.

Why would something like this happen? Wouldn't the field be recreated if the activity was destroyed (because `onCreate` should be called again)?

In what case could something like this happen? I'm trying to reproduce, but no success.

When would the field turn into null? after `onStop()`?

Comment: It should only be null after Android releases that Activity instance. Just how rare is this crash? There are a lot of little things in Android and Java that just happen sometimes.

Comment: @TheWanderer It's happening about once a day, on a newly released version. Already happened to 2 users with different devices.

Comment: @TheWanderer - NEVERMIND! I found the problem. will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the problem was that I was calling the button's click listener from the Activity's `onNewIntent()` on some cases, which is apparently called before `onCreate()`.